# What did the parasite want Hud for?

Tags: cloverfield, cloverfield-2008

After surviving a parasite attack in the subway tunnels, Hud mentions that one of them appeared to have been trying to drag him off instead of killing him on the spot.

> That one that grabbed me, it was trying to drag me away. What's up with that?

**Why was the parasite trying to drag him off, and where to?** The parasites seemed intent on killing (or at least injuring) everyone else.